# Best way to extract a single letter from each row and create a new column in R?

Tags: r, database

Below is an excerpt of the data I'm working with. I am having trouble finding a way to extract the last letter from the sbp.id column and using the results to add a new column to the below data frame called "sex". I initially tried grepl to separate the rows ending in F and the ones ending in M, but couldn't figure out how to use that to create a new column with just M or F, depending on which one is the last letter of each row in the sbp.id column

```
sbp.id newID 
125F   125 
13000M 13000
13120M 13120
13260M 13260
13480M 13480
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex you can extract the last part from `sbp.id`

```
df$sex <- sub('.*([A-Z])$', '\\1', df$sbp.id)
#Also
#df$sex <- sub('.*([MF])$', '\\1', df$sbp.id)
```

Or another way would be to remove all the numbers.

```
df$sex <- sub('\\d+', '', df$sbp.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you know you need the last letter, irrespective of whether the other characters are numbers, digits, or even if the elements all have different lengths, but you still just need the *last character* in the string from every row:

```
df$sex <- substr(df$sbp.id, nchar(df$sbp.id), nchar(df$sbp.id))
```

This works because all of the functions are vectorized by default.